# Websocket error with Cometd on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websocket, cometd

I am using cometd 3.0.1 and deployed it on tomcat 7.0.50. I am getting following exception in my logs and unable to figure out reason for this. Can anyone help understanding possible cause for this or how to proceed in finding and debugging this issue?

P.S. Websocket is working fine, its just this is coming some times.

**EDIT:** Added more logs.
After debugging more into log (after enabling debug logs for cometd) I have following:
From logs I can see this weboscket error might be in relation to connection reset by peer with client id e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn, I grep over logs to see activity of this client and here are my observation:

```
Client uses acknowledgment extension 

[20150423 01:34:48:129 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-71) org.cometd.server.ext.AcknowledgedMessagesSessionExtension#processBatch 77 DEBUG] - Processing batch: last=0, client=-1, server=1 for e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn - last connect 1429767288130 ms ago
[20150423 01:34:48:130 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-71) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#handle 658 DEBUG] - >> {ext={ack=-1}, clientId=e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, id=13749, connectionType=websocket} 
[20150423 01:34:48:131 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-71) org.cometd.server.ext.AcknowledgedMessagesSessionExtension#sendMeta 112 DEBUG] - Sending batch 1 for e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn - last connect 1 ms ago 
[20150423 01:34:48:131 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-71) org.cometd.server.ext.AcknowledgedMessagesSessionExtension#deQueue 126 DEBUG] - Dequeuing 0/0 messages until batch 1 for e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn - last connect 1 ms ago 


[20150423 01:54:04:875 EDT (BayeuxServer2085170520 Scheduler) org.cometd.server.ServerSessionImpl#sweep 158 DEBUG] - Sweeping session e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn - last
 connect 70831 ms ago 
[20150423 01:54:04:876 EDT (BayeuxServer2085170520 Scheduler) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#removeServerSession 532 DEBUG] - Removing session e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m
6uyarn - last connect 70832 ms ago, timed out: true 
[20150423 01:54:04:876 EDT (BayeuxServer2085170520 Scheduler) myapp.cometd.server.util.BayeuxSecurityPolicy#updateStatsForRemovedClient 168 DEBUG] - Removing timedout
 client with ID: e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn 


[20150423 01:57:57:516 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#onMessage 273 DEBUG] - Received [{"channel":"/meta/connect","connectionType":"websocket","id":"19851","clientId":"4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann"}] 
[20150423 01:57:57:516 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#processMessages 305 DEBUG] - Processing {clientId=4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann, channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, connectionType=websocket} 
[20150423 01:57:57:516 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#handle 645 DEBUG] - >  {clientId=4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann, channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, connectionType=websocket} 4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann - last connect 60222 ms ago 
[20150423 01:57:57:517 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#handle 658 DEBUG] - >> {clientId=4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann, channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, connectionType=websocket} 
[20150423 01:57:57:517 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#handle 732 DEBUG] - << {channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, successful=true} 
[20150423 01:57:57:517 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-22) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#processMetaConnect 408 DEBUG] - Scheduled meta connect java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4438c0c5 

[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#cancelMetaConnectTask 260 DEBUG] - Cancelling meta connect task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4438c0c5 
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl#extendSend 1071 DEBUG] - <  {channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, successful=true} 
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#schedule 534 DEBUG] - Flushing 4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann - last connect 60000 ms ago timeout=true metaConnectDelivery=false, metaConnectReply={channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, successful=true}, messages=[]
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#send 435 DEBUG] - Sending 4x10d0bbudn0524iwtfvetfvann - last connect 60000 ms ago, replies=[{channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, successful=true}], messages=[] 
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler$Flusher#process 587 DEBUG] - Processing Entry@5b520f7[messages=0,replies=1] 
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler$Flusher#process 623 DEBUG] - Processing replies [{channel=/meta/connect, id=19851, successful=true}] 
[20150423 01:58:57:517 EDT (pool-2-thread-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport#send 143 DEBUG] - Sending [{"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"19851","successful":true}] 
[20150423 01:58:57:518 EDT (WebSocketServer-/cometd-1) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler$Flusher#process 587 DEBUG] - Processing null


[20150423 01:58:57:609 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-10) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#onError 246 INFO] - WebSocket Error 
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.fillReadBuffer(NioServletInputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.doRead(NioServletInputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.read(AbstractServletInputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:45)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:194)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:189)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:605)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[20150423 01:58:57:610 EDT (http-nio-8109-exec-10) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#onClose 240 DEBUG] - Closing 1006/Connection reset by peer - e15ixjv018sxzarqls0m6uyarn - last connect 363566 ms ago
```

**Update after Debugging:**
In my case one client is using acknowledgment extension, it miss one of the /meta/connect response message from server and hence don't send /meta/connect request, it then try to send a new request but using same client id and fails and it set error code 1006. (This is mostly guessing after seeing server side logs, I don't have client side logs as such.) After that It still send meta connect message (websocket transport) with same client and acknowledgment id of last received message like this "ext":{"ack":2}).

How is this client retaining client id after a disconnect and how is it using websocket if error that is mentioned above is in case of websocket upgrade.

Same thread call `org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketSchedule‌​r#onError and org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketSchedule‌​r#onClose` 
and client id which is logged in onClose method is being sweeped by cometd as It didn't received any message in last 70 seconds, If it has removed this client then how is this client id is coming after WebSocket error.

---

With Jetty I see following websocket related exception

```
[20150421 15:40:40:345 EDT (qtp116211441-61492) org.cometd.websocket.server.AbstractWebSocketTransport$AbstractWebSocketScheduler#onError 246 INFO] - WebSocket Error 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout on Read
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onReadTimeout(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:526)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:496)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems a problem during the upgrade. Have you tried Jetty ? I ask because it will help identifying whether the issue is on the server or on the client.

Comment: @sbordet Update here I have also faced this problem with jetty but exception was different, I don't think it is regarding upgarde in case of jetty

Comment: Seems a client problem to me. The Jetty exception tells that the server is waiting for data from the client, but it's not getting any data, and the Jetty idle timeout expires. You are welcome to join the CometD mailing lists where this issue can be detailed. There is just not enough information here to understand what's going on. Have you tried CometD 3.0.4 and the latest versions of both Jetty and Tomcat ?

Comment: @sbordet I have updated question with one observation and some questions. I ahven't tried above mentioned cometd/jetty version.

Comment: @sbordet with jetty I am getting Closing 1001/Idle Timeout - null whenever am getting WebScoket Error mentioned above

Comment: Sorry, it's incomprehensible. Please pack a reproducible test case that shows the problem, and attach it to an issue at http://bugs.cometd.org/.